# What are the differences between Rich Push Notification and Simple Push Notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios10, richpush

Please explain what are the major differences between Rich Push Notification and Simple Push Notification? And want to know which one is better?

Comment: basically you can push images which get displayed.

Comment: Is this the only difference?

Comment: You can understand from this link https://www.appboy.com/blog/ios-10-rich-notifications/

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Your most welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rich push notifications** have been one of the most-anticipated features of iOS 10. Apple rarely makes an update to iOS that involves perks for both end-users and marketers.

With rich push notifications, marketers will be able to communicate with mobile app audiences in a more creative and interactive way, using photos, audio, and video.

Apple is revamping its notification system on multiple fronts, from the way these notifications are presented to the way users respond. To get a jump on the iOS 10 launch, mobile marketers and app development agencies need to align engineers, creatives, and analysts.

Here’s a break down of the new powerful features and recommendations for adoption.